# Slow code in "inner joins" lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen several posts about lists in python here, but I don't find a correct answer to my question; because it is about optimize a code.

I have a python code to compare two lists. It has to find the same code, and modifying the value of the second positions. It finally works perfectly, but it takes a lot of time. In SQL this query take 2 minuts, no more...., however, here, I spend 15 minutes.... so I don't understand if it is problem of memory or bad code written.

I have two lists. 
The first one [code, points]. The second [code, license]
If the first value(code) in the first list, match with the first value of the second list(code); it has to update the second value  of the first list (points) if the license is equal to 'THIS', for example:

```
itemswithscore = [5675, 0], [6676, 0], [9898, 0], [4545, 0]
itemswithlicense = [9999, 'ATR'], [9191, 'OPOP'], [9898, 'THIS'], [2222, 'PLPL']

for sublist1 in itemswithscore:
    for sublist2 in itemswithlicense:
        if sublist1[0] == sublist2[0]: #this is the "inner join" :)
            if sublist2[1] == 'THIS': #It has to be license 'THIS'
                sublist1[1] += 50 #I add 50 to the score value
```

Finally, I have this list updated in the code 9868:

```
itemswithscore = [5675, 0], [6676, 0], [9898, 50], [4545, 0]
```

It is true that the two lists have 80.000 values everyone.. :(

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll suggest to transform/keep your data structure into/as dicts. In that way, you won't need to iterate over both lists with nested *for* loops - an *O*(n<sup>2</sup>) or *O*(n x m) operation - searching for where the lists' code numbers align before updating the score value.

You'll simply update the value of the score where the key at the corresponding dict matches the search string:

```
dct_score = dict(itemswithscore)
dct_license = dict(itemswithlicense)
for k in dct_score:
    if dct_license.get(k) == 'THIS': # use dict.get in case key does not exist
         dct_score[k] += 50
```

Comment: Amazing! It works perfectly and very very fast. I am sure that it is the best solution.

But I have questions. When you say :
for k in dct_score:
    if dct_license.get(k) == 'THIS'
It could happen that the value 'THIS' can appear in the key or the value of the dictionary, isn't it? 
I mean, you cannot indicate a fixed positions like in a list; for example:  
for sublist in itemswithscore: sublist[1]

Comment: Other question:
I am working with a very big list of (keys, values). 

And I will pass a lot of queries to give more or less scoring (to the "values" part of the list) depending of different queries. 
It will always be better use dictionaries instead of lists?? Because I understand that with lists it will be easier to update the value "column" telling :
for sublist in itemswithscore:
     sublist[1] += 50points

Comment: Might still be better to use dicts. `for k in dct_score: dct_score[k] += 50`

Answer (score 1):

It would be very efficient if you can use pandas.

So You can make two dataframes and merge them on a single column

Something like this

```
itemswithscore = [5675, 0], [6676, 0], [9898, 0], [4545, 0]
itemswithlicense = [9999, 'ATR'], [9191, 'OPOP'], [9898, 'THIS'], [2222, 'PLPL']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(itemswithscore), columns =['code', 'points'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(itemswithlicence), columns=['code', 'license'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2 , on='code', how='inner')
df3 = df3.drop('points', axis=1)
```

Hope this helps, accept if correct

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the slowness is mostly due to the looping itself, which is not very fast in Python. You can speed up the code somewhat by caching variables, like so:

```
for sublist1 in itemswithscore:
    a = sublist1[0]  # Save to variable to avoid repeated list-lookup
    for sublist2 in itemswithlicense:
        if a == sublist2[0]:
            if sublist2[1] == 'THIS':
                sublist1[1] += 50
```

Also, if you happen to know that `'THIS'` does not occur in `itemswithlicense` more than once, you should insert a `break` after you update `sublist1[1]`.

Let me know how much of a different this make.

Comment: Patently untrue.

Comment: @danny What exactly is untrue?

Comment: The entire above statement. List get with an index in Python is always `O(1)`. Whether a variable is used or not does not change this. Yes it saves a lookup. Complexity does not change regardless. The above code is identical in complexity.

Comment: Yes, but `O(1)` may be much less than `O(1)*len(itemswithlicense)`. Complexity isn't all. Eliminating unnecessary repeated lookups can certainly lead to noticeable speed ups.

Comment: @jmd_dk I have tried using caching variables, as you can say in the example. But the time used is exacty the same, almost 15 minutes. I don't like use dictionaries, however, at the moment, is the best solution.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Again, not true. If it were `O(1)*len(itemswithlicense)` that would make it `O(N)`. It is not.