# Python matching strings in list and incrementing values

Tags: python, list, matching

I have two lists one as a global, and one as a local in a function

```
List1 = [[['MP01'], 0], [['MP02'], 0], [['MP03'], 0], [['MP04'], 0], [['MP05'], 0], [['MP06'], 0], [['MP07'], 0], [['MP08'], 0], [['MP09'], 0], [['MP10'], 0], [['MP11'], 0], [['MP12'], 0], [['MP13'], 0], [['MP14'], 0], [['MP15'], 0], [['MP16'], 0], [['MP17'], 0], [['MP18'], 0], [['MP19'], 0], [['MP20'], 0], [['MP21'], 0], [['MP22'], 0], [['MP23'], 0], [['MP24'], 0], [['MP25'], 0], [['MP26'], 0], [['MP27'], 0], [['MP28'], 0], [['MP29'], 0], [['MP30'], 0], [['MP31'], 0], [['MP32'], 0]]

function():
    List2 = [['MP18', 100], ['MP28', 50], ['MP20', 30], ['MP07', 30], ['MP12', 10], ['MP03', 10], ['MP30', 10], ['MP14', 10], ['MP15', 5], ['MP16', 5], ['MP13', 5], ['MP02', 5], ['MP26', 5], ['MP23', 5], ['MP22 ', 5], ['MP01', 5]]

    final_list = [[[a], b+dict(List2).get(a, 0)] for [a], b in List1]
```

Basically, "List2" represents scores that players have achieved in a round of a game (MP18 got 100, MP28 got 50 etc) and "List1" will be used to accumulated the scores for a number of rounds of the game for each player.

What I'm wanting to do is essentially add each players score to "List1" and the problem that I am having is that since "final_list" is within the function, everytime the function is called and produces new values for "List2", insead of adding the new values to "List1" it simply overwrites them. For example, after the first round "List1" will have the updated values for players from "List2":

```
['MP18', 100], ['MP28', 50] etc
```

So MP18 will have 100 points and MP28 will have 50 etc. However, on the second run through of the program (second round) "List2" will have different values for each player for example:

```
[['MP18, 50], [MP28, 100] etc
```

But because the "final_list" is being created from within the function, the first set of scores are being overwritten  by the second instead of the second being added to the first if that makes sense? so on the second run through "List1" will look like:

```
[[MP28, 100], [MP18, 50]
```

As oppose to the desired outcome of:

```
[[MP28, 150], [MP18, 150]]
```

Hopefully this is a bit more of a helpful explanation :D

Comment: Related: [Slow code in “inner joins” lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267727/slow-code-in-inner-joins-lists-in-python). Make `List2` a dict and you can update `List1` in O(1), looking up the `'MP'` values from the dict.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page. [Can someone help me?” is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List1 = [[['MP01'], 0], [['MP02'], 0], [['MP03'], 0], [['MP04'], 0], [['MP05'], 0], [['MP06'], 0], [['MP07'], 0], [['MP08'], 0], [['MP09'], 0], [['MP10'], 0], [['MP11'], 0], [['MP12'], 0], [['MP13'], 0], [['MP14'], 0], [['MP15'], 0], [['MP16'], 0], [['MP17'], 0], [['MP18'], 0], [['MP19'], 0], [['MP20'], 0], [['MP21'], 0], [['MP22'], 0], [['MP23'], 0], [['MP24'], 0], [['MP25'], 0], [['MP26'], 0], [['MP27'], 0], [['MP28'], 0], [['MP29'], 0], [['MP30'], 0], [['MP31'], 0], [['MP32'], 0]]

List2 = [['MP18', 100], ['MP28', 50], ['MP20', 30], ['MP07', 30], ['MP12', 10], ['MP03', 10], ['MP30', 10], ['MP14', 10], ['MP15', 5], ['MP16', 5], ['MP13', 5], ['MP02', 5], ['MP26', 5], ['MP23', 5], ['MP22 ', 5], ['MP01', 5]]
final_list = [[[a], b+dict(List2).get(a, 0)] for [a], b in List1]
```

Then, later on, multiplying the values in the list:

```
new_final_list = [[[a], 2*b] for [a], b in List1]
```

Output:

```
[[['MP01'], 0], [['MP02'], 0], [['MP03'], 0], [['MP04'], 0], [['MP05'], 0], [['MP06'], 0], [['MP07'], 0], [['MP08'], 0], [['MP09'], 0], [['MP10'], 0], [['MP11'], 0], [['MP12'], 0], [['MP13'], 0], [['MP14'], 0], [['MP15'], 0], [['MP16'], 0], [['MP17'], 0], [['MP18'], 0], [['MP19'], 0], [['MP20'], 0], [['MP21'], 0], [['MP22'], 0], [['MP23'], 0], [['MP24'], 0], [['MP25'], 0], [['MP26'], 0], [['MP27'], 0], [['MP28'], 0], [['MP29'], 0], [['MP30'], 0], [['MP31'], 0], [['MP32'], 0]]
```

Edit:

Regarding your recent comment, you can try this to create a `final_list` outside of the function:

```
List1 = [[['MP01'], 0], [['MP02'], 0], [['MP03'], 0], [['MP04'], 0], [['MP05'], 0], [['MP06'], 0], [['MP07'], 0], [['MP08'], 0], [['MP09'], 0], [['MP10'], 0], [['MP11'], 0], [['MP12'], 0], [['MP13'], 0], [['MP14'], 0], [['MP15'], 0], [['MP16'], 0], [['MP17'], 0], [['MP18'], 0], [['MP19'], 0], [['MP20'], 0], [['MP21'], 0], [['MP22'], 0], [['MP23'], 0], [['MP24'], 0], [['MP25'], 0], [['MP26'], 0], [['MP27'], 0], [['MP28'], 0], [['MP29'], 0], [['MP30'], 0], [['MP31'], 0], [['MP32'], 0]]

def some_function():
    List2 = [['MP18', 100], ['MP28', 50], ['MP20', 30], ['MP07', 30], ['MP12', 10], ['MP03', 10], ['MP30', 10], ['MP14', 10], ['MP15', 5], ['MP16', 5], ['MP13', 5], ['MP02', 5], ['MP26', 5], ['MP23', 5], ['MP22 ', 5], ['MP01', 5]]
    global List1
    List1 = [[[a], b+dict(List2).get(a, 0)] for [a], b in List1]
```

Comment: Could I just ask you what the "final_list = [[[a], b+dict(List2).get(a, 0)] for [a], b in List1]" line is actually doing? I am struggling to understand it and it would be very helpful in future to know, thanks.

Comment: @Sean `final_list` is created using a list comprehension. Essentially, it iterations over `List1` and unpacks each string and its corresponding value. Then, the code creates a dictionary out of `List2` by passing it to the `dict` function and access the value stored in the just created dictionary associated with `a`, the string at each iteration. This is performed using `get`, which will return a default zero if the string is not found. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey I'm now having a bit more trouble with my program and wanted to ask for some help if that's ok? The code that you have given me works great however, in my program "List1" is a global variable and "List2" is in a function (it was manipulated earlier in the program). The reason "List1" is a global variable is because I want the values not to be reset every time a function is called however, when the "final_list" list is created, it's created inside of the function and is reset every time the function is called. Is there a way to fix this? I can post my code if that would be helpful to you :D

Comment: @Sean no problem! Please see my recent edit. If I understand correctly, you are trying to create `final_list` without changing `List1`. Please let me know if what I posted above works for you.

Comment: Hey after reading my last comment I don't think I have described very clearly what it is i'm trying to achieve, I have edited my original question above to try and clarify this if you're still willing to lend a hand :)

Comment: @Sean Please see my recent edit and let me know if it works.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help you have no idea how long I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out! I really appreciate it mate :D :D

Comment: @Sean glad to help!